# Change height of jspDrag?

Tags: jquery

I'm using jspScrollpane on a div with a ton of text (a full movie script). Due to the huge amount of content and the limited height of the container div (600px) the vertical scrollbar handle (jspDrag) becomes tiny.

I tried changing the height in the css file but it doesn't work so I'm assuming it is controlled in the js file(?)

How can I set the height of jspDrag regardless of the amount of content?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be frustrating for sure. Since its controlled by the javascript you can override the priority by adding `!important` after that specific line and it will work. See example below. Hope that helps out.

```
.jspDrag {
    height:77px !important;
    top:1px;
    background:url(images/exammpleimage.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use auto autoresize: auto to reinitialize it self when needed. If  the vertical scroll doesn't have the right height, make sure that your content width is not bigger than width of the container. (ex image that is too big, some div with width 100 + margins) etc.

```
$('#content-wrapper').jScrollPane({
    showArrows: true,
    autoReinitialise: true
});
```